# django view cannot get file using request.FILES from ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, file-upload

I tried to submit this form using ajax ,sothat a django view can extract the selected file  from request.FILES and write to a directory on server

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="fileupoadform">{% csrf_token %}
<p>
<label>Select a file
<input type="file" name="fselect" id="fselect"> </input>
</label>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

the view is

```
def ajax_upload(request):
    print 'ajax_upload()'
    print 'request=',request
    to_return = {}
    store_message="failure"
    if (request.is_ajax()) and (request.method == 'POST'):
        print 'is ajax and post'
        print 'request.FILES=',request.FILES
        if request.FILES.has_key('fselect'):
            print "request has key='fselect'"
            file = request.FILES['fselect']
            with open(settings.UPLOADPATH'%s' % file.name, 'wb+') as dest:
                for chunk in file.chunks():
                    dest.write(chunk)
            store_message="success"
    to_return['store_message']= store_message
    print 'to_return=',to_return
    to_return['store_message']= store_message
    serialized = simplejson.dumps(to_return)
    print 'serialized=',serialized
    if store_message == "success":
        print 'suceessfully returning'
        return HttpResponse(serialized, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        print 'failed!! returning'
        return HttpResponseServerError(serialized, mimetype="application/json")
```

I used jquery to make the ajax submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fileupoadform').submit(function(e){
        submitUploadForm(e);            
    });
});
function submitUploadForm(e){
    console.log('clicked submit');
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var file = $('#fselect').get(0).files[0];
    console.log('filename='+file.name)  
    var data = { name:file.name };
    var args = { type:"POST", url:"upload/", data:data, complete:doneAjaxUpload };  
    $.ajax(args);   
}
```

when I tried this ,I got this console output

```
ajax_store_uploaded_file()
request= <WSGIRequest
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {u'name': [u'myfile.srt']}>,
COOKIES:{'csrftoken': 'ca367878345fa9e59adf79hg047a1dvb'},
...
is ajax and post
request.FILES= <MultiValueDict: {}>
to_return= {'store_message': 'failure'}
serialized= {"store_message": "failure"}
failed!! returning
[01/Jun/2012 11:27:26] "POST /myapp/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 28
```

I sense that I am doing something wrong in the django view..Is it that I cannot get the uploaded file from `request.FILES`.In a `non ajax version` of `django view` ,I was able to get the file from request.FILES using `request.FILES['fselect']`

Can somebody help me resolve this?

Comment: Which js library do you use to help uploading?

Comment: @okm ,only jquery and the above script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do ajax file uploads (easily).

Certainly, it doesn't look like you're actually passing a file to your post data, you're just passing the file name -

```
var data = { name:file.name };
```

Check out this question for plugins / info to help do this - [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: that `data` was passed just for testing purposes.A normal form submit has the file data in request.FILES ,why is it that when submit is done thru ajax ,it is missing?

Comment: I think you need to show how "submit is done thru ajax". The fact that the file isn't in request.FILES, suggests it's the javascript that's broken, not the django. What is the code that actually submits the file?

Comment: thanks @Aidan for the reply..finally I got this working by using `formData` and `XMLHttpRequest.send`..